# C# Image to Binary Image - Replacing Pixels with Bitmaps of 1 and 0

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+

### Original Question:

I'm currently trying to convert a Bitmap into a binary Image.
Im taking the average value of a pixel and if it is below a certain threshold the pixel will either be a 1 or a 0.
I do know how to make this work with a textfile. But I am trying to create an Image of ones and zeros.
So each pixel will be converted into a 8x8 Bitmap. It works... sort of, but resulting images are warped and slanted.

How can I make it so that the resulting image won't be slanted?

### Answer:

```c#
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FrameConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap source = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\data\resources\images\monitoring.jpg");
            Bitmap zero = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"c:\data\resources\images\bin_0_1024px_w.png");
            Bitmap one = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"c:\data\resources\images\bin_1_1024px_w.png");

            zero = Resize(zero, 16, 16);
            one = Resize(one, 16, 16);

            var img = CreateBinaryImage(source, zero, one, 0.5225f);
            img.Save("C:\\users\\[user]\\desktop\\test.png");


            Console.Write("Done... Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        private static Bitmap Resize(Image source, int width, int height)
        {
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height, source.PixelFormat);

            destImage.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrap = new ImageAttributes()) {
                    wrap.SetWrapMode(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    g.DrawImage(source, destRect, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrap);
                }
            }
            return destImage;
        }


        private static Bitmap CreateBinaryImage(Bitmap source, Bitmap zero, Bitmap one, float threshold = 0.53f)
        {
            var canvas = new Bitmap(
                source.Width * zero.Width, 
                source.Height * zero.Height, 
                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            unsafe
            {
                var srcData = new ImageData(source, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly);
                var zData   = new ImageData(zero,   ImageLockMode.ReadOnly);
                var oData   = new ImageData(one,    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly);
                var cnvData = new ImageData(canvas, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite);

                try
                {
                    /* Create lists of color arrays of the replacement images.
                    ** Use the bpp property for incrementation to step through the individual pixel values.
                    ** Stores each pixels RGB values as bytes. */
                    var zPixel = new List<Color[]>();
                    var oPixel = new List<Color[]>();

                    for (int y=0; y<zData.Hip; y++)
                    {
                        /* Pointer to the desired row of pixels */
                        byte* zScan = zData.FirstPixel + y * zData.Bytes;
                        byte* oScan = oData.FirstPixel + y * oData.Bytes;

                        /* We only want to store the Pixels color which is why we need to devide by Byte per pixel */
                        Color[] z = new Color[zData.Bytes / zData.Bpp];
                        Color[] o = new Color[oData.Bytes / oData.Bpp];

                        int index = 0;
                        for (int x=0; x<zData.Bytes; x+=zData.Bpp)
                        {
                            z[index] = Color.FromArgb(zScan[x + 2], zScan[x + 1], zScan[x + 0]);
                            o[index] = Color.FromArgb(oScan[x + 2], oScan[x + 1], oScan[x + 0]);
                            index++;
                        }
                        zPixel.Add(z);
                        oPixel.Add(o);
                    }

                    int cx = 0; /* X-position on canvas */
                    int cy = 0; /* Y-position on canvas */
                    for (int y0=0; y0<srcData.Hip; y0++)
                    {
                        byte* srcScan = srcData.FirstPixel + y0 * srcData.Bytes;
                        for (int x0=0; x0<srcData.Bytes; x0+=srcData.Bpp)
                        {
                            // calculate average to determine if pixel will be 1 or 0
                            float avg = ((srcScan[x0 + 2] & 0xff) / 255f +
                                         (srcScan[x0 + 1] & 0xff) / 255f +
                                         (srcScan[x0 + 0] & 0xff) / 255f) / 3;
                            avg = Math.Min(1f, .35f + .65f * avg);

                            /* Determine which colors/pixels to use to reduce length of code */
                            List<Color[]> pixels = avg < threshold ? oPixel : zPixel;

                            /* Calculate start indizes on canvas */
                            cx = (x0 / srcData.Bpp) * pixels[0].Length;
                            cy = y0 * pixels.Count;
                            int y1 = 0;
                            while (y1 < pixels.Count && cy < canvas.Height)
                            {
                                int x1 = 0;
                                while (x1 + zData.Bpp < pixels[y1].Length && cx < canvas.Width)
                                {
                                    /* Increment the start indizes of the canvas with the current 
                                    ** Pixel position of the replacement image. */
                                    cnvData.SetPixel(cx + x1, cy + y1, pixels[y1][x1]);
                                    x1++;
                                }
                                y1++;
                            }
                        }
                    }                    
                }
                finally
                {
                    srcData.Dispose();
                    zData.Dispose();
                    oData.Dispose();
                    cnvData.Dispose();
                }
                return canvas;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```c#
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace FrameConvert
{
    public unsafe class ImageData : IDisposable
    {
        public Bitmap Bitmap { get; }
        public BitmapData Bits { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Width in Pixel
        /// </summary>
        public int Wip { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Height in Pixel
        /// </summary>
        public int Hip { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Byte per Pixel
        /// </summary>
        public int Bpp { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Pointer to first pixel of Image
        /// </summary>
        public unsafe byte* FirstPixel { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Stride of Image
        /// </summary>
        public int Stride { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Amount of Bytes per Pixel row (Math.Abs(Stride))
        /// </summary>
        public int Bytes { get; }

        public ImageData(Bitmap bitmap, ImageLockMode lockMode)
        {
            Bitmap = bitmap;
            Bits = bitmap.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                lockMode,
                bitmap.PixelFormat);
            Bpp = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
            Hip = Bits.Height;
            Wip = Bits.Width;
            FirstPixel = (byte*)Bits.Scan0;
            Stride = Bits.Stride;
            Bytes = Math.Abs(Stride);
        }


        public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            int px = Bpp * x + Stride * y;
            if (Bpp % 3 == 0)
            {
                return Color.FromArgb(
                    FirstPixel[px + 2],
                    FirstPixel[px + 1],
                    FirstPixel[px + 0]);
            }
            else if (Bpp % 4 == 0)
            {
                return Color.FromArgb(
                    FirstPixel[px + 3],
                    FirstPixel[px + 2],
                    FirstPixel[px + 1],
                    FirstPixel[px + 0]);
            }
            return Color.Empty;
        }


        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color c)
        {
            int px = Bpp * x + Stride * y;
            if (Bpp % 3 == 0)
            {
                FirstPixel[px + 0] = c.B;
                FirstPixel[px + 1] = c.G;
                FirstPixel[px + 2] = c.R;
            }
            else if (Bpp % 4 == 0)
            {
                FirstPixel[px + 0] = c.B;
                FirstPixel[px + 1] = c.G;
                FirstPixel[px + 2] = c.R;
                FirstPixel[px + 3] = c.A;
            }
        }


        ~ImageData() { Dispose(false); }
        public void Dispose() { Dispose(true); }
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
            try { Bitmap.UnlockBits(Bits); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrfXk.png)

[Binary 0 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT9fA.png)

[Binary 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdU2M.png)

Comment: You have to adjust for padding. Width in byte should be a multiple of 4. Or try your code again using images whose widths is a multiple of 4. For example, 200, or 400

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Hi, thanks for your reply. This is however not the issue. The first image has a resolution of 1920x1080 and the second one 240x240. Both images are therefore multiples of 4. I think the real issue lies within Graphics.DrawImage() since it scales images automatically. I will try to set each Pixel manually and see if that changes anything.